# C# - Issue reading deleted rows from CSV using CSVContext Read() and Count()

Tags: c#, excel, csv, csvhelper

In my code, I am downloading a CSV file with 250 rows.

The CSV file is amended in Excel where rows are deleted, leaving only the header row and a single record. I then reupload the file to the application for processing

Here is a snippet of the upload code from my controller:

```
CsvFileDescription csvFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
    {
      SeparatorChar = ',',
      FirstLineHasColumnNames = true,
      IgnoreUnknownColumns = true
    };

    try
    {
      CsvContext csv = new CsvContext();
      IEnumerable<ResidentFeeCSVRow> csvRows = csv.Read<ResidentFeeCSVRow>(csvUpload.FilePath, csvFileDescription);
```

If I return csvRows.Count(), the value is 250, the original amount of rows in the file. I need this to only show 1 row as expected.

If I loop through csvRows, I get 1 record which contains values as expected, and 249 records that are null.

Does Excel/CSV file store the row range anywhere so it makes it seem as if there is still 250 rows?

Can anyone advise what may be causing this and how I can overcome it?

Comment: Excel produces `xlsx` files, a zip package containing XML files. CSV though is a text format. What does that text file look like? If you try to load a file and it still has 250 rows it means you *didn't* delete them after all or didn't save the changes. Or you're reading the wrong file

Comment: Lots of empty rows with commas in the text file. So if the end user is deleting the rows in the CSV within Excel, or at least thinks they are, how can this be overcome either in Excel or code so as not to count these empty rows.

Comment: those aren't empty rows, they are *full* rows, whose fields contain emtpy strings. They are rows nonetheless. You *didn't* delete the rows in Excel - you didn't select them, right click and choose `Delete Rows`. This has nothing to do with code

Comment: In any case, you don't need Excel to delete all rows except one. Write a LINQ query that reads the rows from the original CSV, selects the one you want and writes a *new* csv containing only that one item

Comment: Thanks, deleting the rows themselves will work

Comment: You can check for an empty string in your key column if you want to handle this somewhat gracefully in your code. Because in my experience, people do this all the time in Excel, and it causes problems with ETL.